# How to run commands on a remote computer using PSExec and PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install an .exe program remotely to many workstations in the domain.

The command I am trying to run in the remote computer's PowerShell instance:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\$Computer /s cmd /c %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\FileShare\Software\DellSupportAssist.ps1
```

And the script I am calling in the command above:

```
 #Retrieves a list of computers in AD.
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "Workstation*"' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
#Opens a remote session into the computer.
.\PsExec.exe C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe \\$Computer

#Installs Dell SupportAssist for each computer
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://downloads.dell.com/serviceability/catalog/SupportAssistInstaller.exe" -OutFile "C:\Users\$env:Username\Downloads\SupportAssistInstaller.exe"
Start-Process "C:\Users\$env:Username\Downloads\SupportAssistInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait -NoNewWindow
Write-Host "Installing Dell SupportAssist on $Computer" -ForegroundColor Green

#Checks whether Dell SupportAssist was successfully installed or not
if (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -ComputerName $Computer | Where {$_.Name -match "Dell Support*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) {
    Write-Host "Dell SupportAssist was successfully installed on $Computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else {
    Write-Host "Dell SupportAssist was not successfully installed on $Computer" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

exit
```

}

I am having the following issues:

- 'Target name incorrect' (for half of the computers in the domain.)
- .\PsExec.exe : The term '\FileShare\Software\DellSupportAssist.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable (for the computers I can connect to in the domain)

Comment: Why aren't you using PowerShell remoting?

Comment: @boxdog I get the following error message **Connecting to remote server COMPUTER2 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the 
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local 
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.**

Comment: @boxdog each computer has the same configuration/setup. It works for some computers but not all in the domain.

Comment: @Zoys: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/555966 / https://4sysops.com/wiki/enable-powershell-remoting/

Most likely you'll need to enable winrm or adjust firewall rules.

Comment: @P-L i am unable to go around to several hundred computers and enable winrm config. is there no other way to force enable it?

Comment: @Zoys, of course! This needs to be configured as a Group Policy Object (GPO).

Comment: @P-L Thank you, you've helped me a lot.